# Why is the first field in 'ls - l' not a 'f' when viewing a file?

Tags: terminal, ls

When I do 'ls -l', I might get something like this:

`-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root       209 Mar 30 17:41 fname`

The first field is the `-`, which means this is a file.

If it was a directory and not a file, the first field would be a `d`.

Why did the creators of Unix decide to use a `d` for directory, which is clear and intuitive, yet use a `-` for a file? Why not use `f` for a file?

**Edit**
Really interesting responses. Lots of different ideas, and they all make sense, even if some seem more inadvertently true than implemented for that reason and/or are documented as that being the reason.

Comment: Directory is a file, just a special type. So it makes sense  to indicate that's a special type of file with d, but it's pointless for regular file.  See https://askubuntu.com/q/1073802/295286 and    https://askubuntu.com/a/1073805/295286  There's a few historical notes there on the topic.

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions or any parts of the answers need clarification.

Comment: If you assume that regular files are the most common thing to be found in a directory listing, then representing them by a small character like `-` makes the rarer file types (everything else) stand out.

Comment: [Understanding UNIX permissions and file types](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/183994/86440) might be relevant here.

Comment: There's this [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/103114/117549), but the wording of *this* question asks "why" and that's much harder to answer.

Answer (score 12):

Historically, one of the big design decisions in Unix was to consider everything as a file.¹ This transpires in early `ls` and `stat` manpages; for example, in V3 (February 1973), [the `stat` manpage](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/Research-V3-Snapshot-Development/man/man1/stat.1) (which describes the mode used by `ls`) says that

> The mode is a six-character string whose characters mean the
>   following:
>
> 1. `s`: file is small (smaller than 4096 bytes)
>      `l`: file is large
> 2. `d`: file is a directory
>      `x`: file is executable
>      `u`: set user ID on execution
>      `-`: none of the above

etc.

In V4 (October 1973) the mode starts to resemble what we have today; [the `ls` manpage](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/Research-V4-Snapshot-Development/man/man1/ls.1) says

> The mode printed under the `-l` option contains 10 characters which are interpreted as follows:
>
> the first character is
>   `d`   if the entry is a directory;
>   `b`   if the entry is a block-type special file;
>   `c`   if the entry is a character-type special file;
>   `-`   if the entry is a plain file.
>
> The next 9 characters are interpreted
>   as three sets of three bits each.

So it seems the creators of Unix really thought that a plain file is “just” the default, nothing special, so it doesn’t deserve a character — everything is a file, and only files which aren’t plain files need additional description. One could think of `-` as signaling the absence of “specialness”.

¹ Strictly speaking, the design decision was to make everything accessible through the file system, not to consider everything as a file; but as a result, everything had to be made available as some sort of file, and this required being able to distinguish different types of files. See [section 3 of *The UNIX Time-Sharing System*](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/cacm.pdf).

Comment: wait a minute tho....if a plain text file is the expected default, then shouldn't Unix say, "Hey guys, this is just the default thing we like, so give it a hearty "YES"!'.  But the dash seems to represent a 'no'.  Like 'r-x' means 'no' for 'write'. The dash's meaning is going back and forth as a Yes and a No, so to speak (at least if you look at it this way...)

Comment: I take the dash as meaning “default”. Files are plain files (not plain *text* files, just plain files, as opposed to directories and special files) by default, unreadable by default (*i.e.* if they don’t have the read bit set), etc.

Comment: A file in computer science is just collection of bytes organized together in some logical form. What normally users think of a "file" is not the same meaning to the computer. So think of it as "collection of bytes". Unix/Linux itself won't really care what particular arrangement of bytes that is, besides the special types relevant to the OS itself - those types that Stephen cited in the answer.  Now, special applications, like your desktop environment or GNOME specifically, those additionally will look at the header of file - that's called mime type.

Comment: @Sergiy bit of a nitpick, the rest of your comment is fine, but no, the MIME type isn’t the header... ([How are file types known if not from file suffix?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/207276/86440))

Comment: @StephenKitt Agreed, I probably should have explained that from the magic number, which is the header part.

Comment: @Sergiy, no, there is no header. There are heuristics to try to guess a file’s type but there is no guaranteed header, or magic number, etc. All sorts of [fun and games](https://speakerdeck.com/ange) can be had by abusing those guesses.

Comment: @StephenKitt   Technically, the header is irrelevant to the OS itself, so there your statement "there is no header" holds true, and yes it's not guaranteed and OS itself doesn't require it. But when we're talking about specific applications, like GNOME or `file` utility - those do take first several bytes of a file into account.  That's what I was trying to deliver in my first comment.

Comment: @Sergiy I know what you’re trying to convey, but in my experience it’s too simplistic and it ends up confusing users. `file`, and the shared MIME database, apply a sequence of detection tests, some of which look at the first few bytes of a file. But claiming that the first few bytes of a file give an indication of its type gives readers the wrong impression. There is no guaranteed way of determining a file type (unlike Mac OS Classic or PalmOS where each file had a type and creator code).

Comment: @StephenKitt OK, I should have expressed that better. Then again, I can only do so much in the comments.